# Get GCLID thru Measurement Protocol

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4, measurement-protocol

Is it possible to pull users GCLID thru the Measurment Protocol? I found this docs https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters but not sure if they reference exact params

I tried hitting the endpoint but I'm not seeing the param